# Tweepy get user favorited tweets in the last week

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Using Tweepy I would like to retrieve all the tweets a user A favorited in the last week.

Is it possible? How can I do it with tweepy?

I searched tweepy documentation, but it seems like what I got  is the datetime when a third user B tweeted the tweet that user A favorited.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you have your answer. This is a weakness in the Twitter API - it only shows you when a Tweet was created, not when the favourite was made.

You can see what is returned in the [GET favorites/list documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/favorites/list).

Comment: @f126ck what was the hack you used?